# Find out if sitecore item was published

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-ecm

I'm trying to find out if I can determine if and when a Sitecore item was published / un-published.

Some background: The issue was that an ECM recipient item in Sitecore was not published, preventing an ECM email from being sent. We've been told they have been sending emails using this recipient item, so I'm trying to determine if it was ever published, and if it was, then when it was un-published.

So far I've had a look in the PublishQueue, EventQueue, and History tables on Master - but couldn't see anything obvious - also couldn't find anything obvious in the logs by just searching on the item ID.

Cheers,
Henry

Answer (score 2):

You could add the Publish Status of items to the Gutter. 
Here is how: [How to flag new items as unpublished items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172346/sitecore-flag-new-items-as-unpublished-items)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many options.

- "Publishing Viewer" in "Publishing" tab
- "Log Viewer" to see details
- If you use workflow for items, check your "Work Box" if there is any queues.